# r convert string to use with $operator

Tags: r, operator-keyword

I am a secondary school teacher hoping to use R as part of a statistics course

I have used the `split()` function on the `outcome_of_care` matrix

```
bystate <- split(outcome_of_care,outcome_of_care$State)
```

and then obtained the entries with state `"TX"`

```
ans <-bystate$TX
```

but I want be able to change the state name to `"CA"` or whatever

This is my effort so far

```
st <- "TX"
st <- paste("bystate$", st, sep ="")
st
ans <- as.name(st)
```

Comment: `st <- "TX"; bystate[, st]`

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-data-frame-column-using-and-the-name-of-the-column-in-a-variable/18228613#18228613)